# Replacing a letter with a word

Tags: python

I am wondering how to write a function that replaces a letter with a word without using any built in functions. For example, `eyeForI(“William”)` returns `“Weyelleyeam”` which replaces every `i` with `eye.`

I know how to do this with a built in function which I already wrote something similar here (though in this case it changes a word with a different word):

```
def stringChange(s):
    for old, new in (
        ("can't", "can not"),
        ("shouldn't", "should not"),
        ("don't", "do not"),
        ("won't", "will not"),
        ):
        s = s.replace(old, new)
    if "!" in s:
        s=s.upper()

    return s
```

But I do not know how to write it without using any built in functions.

I know I must use a `for` loop.

Comment: Do you know how string concatenation and slicing works?

Comment: @kroolik No. I am currently reading [this right now](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/). But I do not recall reading anything about concatenation nor slicing.

Comment: Isn't a side effect of this that if you for instance replace `a` with `ab` and then `b` with `c`, more `b`'s will be replaced than you intend?

Comment: What is your working definition of a built in function that you want to avoid? Because in Python, even item access using [] calls a hidden method on the object. What about `len`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something for you to try and take apart. Rather than a for loop, it involves generators, dictionary with a default argument to `get`, and `join`. You can iterate through a string, which means you do not need to convert it into a list first.

```python
s1 = "William"
subs = {'i': 'eye'}
s2 = ''.join(subs.get(c, c) for c in s1)
print(s2)
```

Here is a solution that does not call anything that would reasonably be called a function or method. It is not very "pythonic" however. It would be difficult to extend due to the hard-coding of the condition, and repeated addition of strings is not preferred.

```
def eyeForI(word):
    result = ""  # create an empty string so we can add to it
    for c in word:  # c will be set to each character in turn
        if c == 'i':
            result += 'eye'  # add the word to the end of result
        else:
            result += c  # add the letter to the end of result
    return result
assert eyeForI("William") == "Weyelleyeam"  # test it works
```

Comment: I rather use a loop because I am following [this book](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/).

Comment: Thanks Jason! I like this code too. Do you mind if you can write an explanation of what is going on using `#`? Because I did think of using `+=` but I didn't know how to apply them correctly in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable so you'll want to convert it to a list, make changes, then convert back to a string.  For your example,

```
def eyeForI(word):
    word = list(word)
    j = 0
    while j < len(word):
        if word[j] == 'i':
            word[j] = 'eye'
        j += 1
    word = ''.join(word)
    return word
```

If you are just learning the control structures, it's worth mentioning that this can also be accomplished with a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

```
def eyeForI(word):
    # convert the string word into a list
    # word = ['W', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'i', 'a', 'm']
    word = list(word)
    # loop over indices of the list.  len(word) = 7 so i runs from 0-6
    for j in xrange(len(word)):
        if word[j] == 'i':      # if the j'th item in word == "i"
            word[j] = 'eye'     # change it to "eye"
    word = ''.join(word)        # join method, explained below
    return word
```

The `join` method can be confusing at first.  It will join all the elements of its argument (in this case `word`) using the string that calls it as a separator (in this case `''`).  So we just say, "join the elements of word using an empty string to separate them."  Note that you can also build another string from scratch using the `+` operator and iterating through the original `word` string if you like (see other answers).

Comment: Hmm, I am not understanding. I tried running your code on calico but it didnt work. But do we still have to use a built in function like `''.join()`? Because I rather not use any built in functions.

Comment: I didn't know of calico until recently, but python 3 was acting strange in my computer and calico is a language very similar to python. Which is what I am using now.

Comment: Calico appears to be an IDE that supports several languages, including Python, rather than a language.

Comment: btw, check @JasonS's answer for making a string w/o using `join`

Answer (score 2):

I like list comprehensions :)

- Why write a whole function if all you need is to perform an specific task which can be done in one line.

*You can create a list of the letters:*

```
>>> print [letter if letter is not 'i' else 'eye' for letter in "william" ]
['w', 'eye', 'l', 'l', 'eye', 'a', 'm']
```

*and use the `join` function to put them together:*

```
>>> print "".join([letter if letter is not 'i' else 'eye' for letter in "william" ])
weyelleyeam
```